# How to get variable in string in SASS?

Tags: css, sass

In SASS, I have this

```
background-image:url('/folder/pic.png');
```

but I want to do something like this

```
$scope : "folder";
background-image:url('/[$scope]/pic.png');
```

how can I do this in SASS?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close - you can use `#{$var}` to include variables in strings and other tricky places.

The syntax would be this:

```
$scope: "folder";
background-image: url('/#{$scope}/pic.png');
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do it like this:

```
background-image:url(/#{$scope}/pic.png);
```

Answer (score 1):

> background-image:url('/' + $scope + '/pic.png');

or

> background-image:url('/#{$scope}/pic.png');